# OpenACC present clause update data

Tags: c++, c++11, gpu, openacc

I am trying to do openACC optimizations for many body simulations. Currently, I am facing a problem which lead to memory problem in below

> call to `cuStreamSynchronize` returned error 700: Illegal address during kernel execution
>   call to `cuMemFreeHost` returned error 700: Illegal address during kernel execution
>   `srun`: error: jrc0017: task 0: Exited with exit code 1

I am using `pgc++` compiler and my compiler flags are `-acc -Minfo=accel -ta=tesla -fast -std=c++11` and I don't want to use `-ta=tesla:managed` because I want to organise memory by myself.

```
#pragma acc kernels present(sim.part.rx, sim.part.ry, sim.part.rz, sim.part.vx, sim.part.vy, sim.part.vz) 
{
  for(int idx = 0; idx < sim.num; ++idx) {     // Loop over target particle
    float
      prx = sim.part.rx[idx],                   // my position
      pry = sim.part.ry[idx],
      prz = sim.part.rz[idx];
    float Fx = 0.f, Fy = 0.f, Fz = 0.f;          // Force
    #pragma acc loop 
    for(int jdx = 0; jdx < sim.num; ++jdx) {   // Loop over interaction partners
      if(idx != jdx) {                          // No self-force
        const float dx = prx - sim.part.rx[jdx]; // Distance to partner
        const float dy = pry - sim.part.ry[jdx];
        const float dz = prz - sim.part.rz[jdx];
        const float h  = 1.f/sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz + eps);
        const float h3 = h*h*h;
        Fx += dx*h3;                            // Sum up force
        Fy += dy*h3;
        Fz += dz*h3;
      }
    }
    sim.part.vx[idx] += sim.mass*dt*Fx;         // update velocity
    sim.part.vy[idx] += sim.mass*dt*Fy;
    sim.part.vz[idx] += sim.mass*dt*Fz;
  }
}
```

If I delete the code in below

```
sim.part.vx[idx] += sim.mass*dt*Fx;         // update velocity
sim.part.vy[idx] += sim.mass*dt*Fy;
sim.part.vz[idx] += sim.mass*dt*Fz;
```

my code is able to run without problem. But I got memory problem if I un-comment them. It seems that `sim.part.vx` are try to update the data but compiler don't know which lead to the memory problem.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Which compiler are you using for this?

Comment: @talonmies I am using pgc++

Comment: Compiler bug? Have you asked the site staff who operate this Cray for support?

Comment: I think it is compiler bug, that pgc++ are not good at dealing with struct. I will report that. If I use only array there is no problem.

Comment: Have you tried taking sim.mass out from the struct to a separate scalar variable?

Comment: @Ruyk Yes, that is how I solved the problem now...but thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: @Lbj_x @Ruyk I'd assumed that `sim.part.vx` was the problem, but if `sim.mass` is the problem, try adding `firstprivate(sim.mass)`. The default behavior for scalars is to make them firstprivate, but the compiler may be getting tripped up by the fact that it's in a struct.

Comment: @jefflarkin Actually, it sim.part.vx was the problem, the compiler flag I was using was not able to distinguish this struct even if I delete `sim.mass` I still get segmentation fault

Comment: @Lbj_x It may be that the struct itself isn't on the device. A common workaround is to create pointers to the structure members and work with them instead. For instance `float *rx = sim.part.rx` and then `present(rx)`, but then you have to update every reference to `rx`. This isn't ideal, which is why the OpenACC technical committee is working on a better solution for structures.

Comment: @Lbj_x Is sim a C `struct` or C++ `class`?

Comment: @jefflarkin exactly! that is how I did to solve the problem:D you can post below I will accept it.

Comment: @jefflarkin is C `struct`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that `sim` and `sim.part` are not on the device (or the compiler doesn't realize that they're on the device. As a workaround, can you try introducing pointers to those arrays directly?

```
float *rx = sim.part.rx, *ry = sim.part.ry, *rz = sim.part.rz, 
      *vx = sim.part.vx, *vy = sim.part.vy, *vz = sim.part.vz;
#pragma acc kernels present(rx, ry, rz, vx, vy, vz) 
{
  for(int idx = 0; idx < sim.num; ++idx) {     // Loop over target particle
    float
      prx = rx[idx],                   // my position
      pry = ry[idx],
      prz = rz[idx];
    float Fx = 0.f, Fy = 0.f, Fz = 0.f;          // Force
    #pragma acc loop 
    for(int jdx = 0; jdx < sim.num; ++jdx) {   // Loop over interaction partners
      if(idx != jdx) {                          // No self-force
        const float dx = prx - rx[jdx]; // Distance to partner
        const float dy = pry - ry[jdx];
        const float dz = prz - rz[jdx];
        const float h  = 1.f/sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz + eps);
        const float h3 = h*h*h;
        Fx += dx*h3;                            // Sum up force
        Fy += dy*h3;
        Fz += dz*h3;
      }
    }
    vx[idx] += sim.mass*dt*Fx;         // update velocity
    vy[idx] += sim.mass*dt*Fy;
    vz[idx] += sim.mass*dt*Fz;
  }
}
```

How are sim and sim.part allocated? It's possible to use unstructured data directives in the constructor and destructor to make sure that sim and sim.part are on the device too. If you've already done this, then another possible solution is to add `present(sim, sim.part)` to your existing present clause so the compiler knows that you've already taken care of those data structures too.